# Shiny/DT: Show Child Rows Upon Initial Load

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatables, dt

**The problem:** I have a DataTable object in a Shiny app that utilizes child rows, which can be clicked upon and expanded to show additional information about the row. However, I can't figure out how to have the child rows visible/expanded when the table initially loads.

When the app loads initially, the child rows are hidden/closed, and the data table looks like this:
[image]

However, I want the initial load of the table to mimic what it looks like when I click on the "+" sign for every row (which expands/displays the child row)... for example:

[image]

Here is an example with some dummy data:

```
# Load packages
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Set up dummy data frame.
df = data.frame(
  expand_child_row = "&oplus;",
  col1 = c(1, 2, 3),
  col2 = c("a", "b", "c"),
  child_row_col = "additional_info"
)

# Define app UI
ui = shiny::fluidPage(
  
  DT::DTOutput(outputId = "example_table")
  
)

# Define app server
server = function(input, output) {
  
  output$example_table = DT::renderDataTable({
    
    dt = DT::datatable(
      data = df,
      options = list(
        dom = "t",
        columnDefs = list(
          list(visible = FALSE, targets = 3),
          # Define options for child row column
          list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = 0)
        )
      ),
      rownames = FALSE,
      escape = FALSE,
      callback = DT::JS("
      
        // Change mouse to pointer when hovering over expand plus sign
        table.column(0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});
        
        // Function to format the child row text
        var format = function(d) {
          return '<div style=\"background-color:#f9f7fe; padding: .5em;\"> ' + d[3] + '</div>';
        };
        
        // Function to toggle (show/hide) child row visibility upon click.
        table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
          var td = $(this), row = table.row(td.closest('tr'));
          if (row.child.isShown()) {
            row.child.hide();
            td.html('&oplus;');
          } else {
            row.child(format(row.data())).show();
            td.html('&CircleMinus;');
          }
        });
        
      ")
    )
    
    return(dt)
    
  })
  
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to get it so that the initial load of the data table appears with *all* child rows being shown (like in the 2nd image)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a little js below and achieved what you want.

make sure the word `example_table` in `$("#example_table")` matches the `DToutput` ID.

```r
# Load packages
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Set up dummy data frame.
df = data.frame(
    expand_child_row = "&oplus;",
    col1 = c(1, 2, 3),
    col2 = c("a", "b", "c"),
    child_row_col = "additional_info"
)

# Define app UI
ui = shiny::fluidPage(
    DT::DTOutput(outputId = "example_table"),
    tags$script(
        '
        $("#example_table").on("draw.dt", function(){
            $(this).find("tbody tr td:first-child").trigger("click");
        })
        '
    )

)

# Define app server
server = function(input, output) {

    output$example_table = DT::renderDataTable({

        dt = DT::datatable(
            data = df,
            options = list(
                dom = "t",
                columnDefs = list(
                    list(visible = FALSE, targets = 3),
                    # Define options for child row column
                    list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = 0)
                )
            ),
            rownames = FALSE,
            escape = FALSE,
            callback = DT::JS("

        // Change mouse to pointer when hovering over expand plus sign
        table.column(0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});

        // Function to format the child row text
        var format = function(d) {
          return '<div style=\"background-color:#f9f7fe; padding: .5em;\"> ' + d[3] + '</div>';
        };

        // Function to toggle (show/hide) child row visibility upon click.
        table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
          var td = $(this), row = table.row(td.closest('tr'));
          if (row.child.isShown()) {
            row.child.hide();
            td.html('&oplus;');
          } else {
            row.child(format(row.data())).show();
            td.html('&CircleMinus;');
          }
        });
      ")
        )

        return(dt)

    })

}

shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: this is absolutely perfect, thank you so much.